# ASP MVC 3 server side WP7 client side application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm going to create an application consisting of 2 modules.

- Server side based on asp mvc 3 services. This is supposed to provide data from a sql server database to a bunch of WP7 clients.
- Client side on WP7. This one is supposed to retrieve data from the server and store it in local database.

I suppose it's a good idea to have only one set of models for both of those apps and I'd like to use Entity Framework.

I'm considering the following approach:

Put these 2 projects on one solution. In server side app generate Entity framework models form a sql server database. Use them in both apps.

A service on the server should use the model to retrieve data and than return them as an oData xml. The WP7 app should grab this oData xml and using the same models store it in local database.

I've never done anything similar before so I'm not sure if is a good approach. Will it work? Any remarks appreciated.

**EDIT**

I already have a working service returning data. I also created a test SL app which grabs data. I uses the Entity Framework models from the server app. The next step is to create a WP7 app, grab the data to Entity Framework model (the same way as in SL app I mentioned before).

Here you can see how I create a read context through a service:

```
svc = new BlogContext(new Uri("/BlogService.svc", UriKind.Relative));
var q = svc.Blogs;
```

But there still is a problem I don't know how to solve. How to create a context to write to a WP7 local database?

Comment: persisting entity objects in a separate server?  As I recall that is practically impossible...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs No, it's not what I mean. I just want the two projects share the same model classes and send 'objects' by oData services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can work; I'm doing something very similar in one of my apps (albeit swapping oData for a JSON/OAuth API)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like [Project Linker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e730577-d11c-4f2e-8e2b-cbb87f76c044/%20%22Project%20Linker) to get a multi-targeted solution, because libraries are not shareable between Silverlight (WP7) and the server (.NET).

Stick to POCO classes, and use the EF POCO class templates exclusively. Use the EF models themselves only on the server. I don't think you can use DataAnnotations in Silverlight, so you may need to roll your own validation.